# Guessing Game with functions c++

Tags: c++

I am writing a guessing game program using functions for each thing, I keep getting errors saying function isn't set so when I try to call it, it isn't working. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. 
I know I have arguments for the functions that aren't being used but I cant seem to figure out where or how I should include those in the function themself.

I am fairly new to programming/c++ so please no negative comments I am just trying to get as much help as I can.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int getGuess(string prompt);
string getRank(int guessCount);
bool getPlayAgain(string prompt);
void playOneGame();

int main(){

    srand(time(0));
    int number = rand() % 100 + 1;
    string prompt = getGuess();
    do(
        playOneGame();
    )while(getPlayAgain())

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

int getGuess(string prompt){
    int num;
    int guessCount = 0;
    prompt = cout << "Please enter a number between 1-100: ";
    cin >> num;

    if(num > 100){
        cout << "Please enter a number between 1-100: " << endl;

    }
    if(num < 1){
        cout << "Please enter a number between 1-100: " << endl;
    }
    if(num <= 100){
        cout << "The number you guessed is: " << num << endl; 
        guessCount++;
    }

}

string getRank(int guessCount){
    switch(guessCount){
        case 1: 
        case 2:
        case 3: cout << "Lucky!" << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
        case 5: 
        case 6: cout << "Awesome";
            break;
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9: cout << "Good";
            break;
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12: cout << "Meh";
            break;
        case 13:
        case 14:
        case 15: cout <<"Poor";
            break;
        default: cout << "Pathetic";
    }

}

bool getPlayAgain(string prompt){
    bool done = false;
    int num1;
    while(!done){
        cout << "Enter 1 to play again or 2 to quit: ";
        cin >> num1;

        if(num1 == 2){
            break;
        }
        else(
            getGuess();
        )

    }


}

void playOneGame(){
    getGuess();
    getRank();
    getPlayAgain();

}
```

---

Comment: A few questions to help you get started: 1) How many arguments does `int getGuess(string prompt);` require? 2) How  many arguments does `string prompt = getGuess();` provide? 3) What data type does `int getGuess(string prompt);` return? 4) What datatype does `string prompt = getGuess();` accept?

Comment: A recommendation: write less code before stopping to compile and test. You find mistakes faster and will have fewer mistakes to have to sort out all at once. Bugs tend to gang up on you and the more bugs you have the more confusing they get. Even if you only have a few bugs, giving them more code to hide in cedes them an unnecessary advantage.

Comment: `string getRank(int guessCount){` expects to return a string not print one. By not returning a string you have Undefined Behvior.

Comment: I will write less code in future situations,
To answer your questions if I am correct, int getGuess(string prompt) requires one aruments, string prompt = getGuess() provides one arguement I think?
the data type returned is int for getGuess, and the datatype string prompt returns a string so I see that mistake.

Comment: No in ` int getGuess(string prompt)` you promised the compiler to return an `int` but fail to do so. There is no `return` at all in the function.

Comment: Arguments go inside the brackets. `getGuess()` provides zero arguments.

Answer (score 1):

No return statement in getguess() function but function signature is int return type.
Getguess() accepts prompt parameter as input but not used inside the function.